# Getting the text of a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, undefined, href

So I'm trying to develop my own extension for Chrome. For a first try, I want to create an extension that gathers all the links in the page into one place.

Since I don't know what kind of links there are, I have to get the link `href` and link text by selecting their attributes.

The link `href` attribute selector worked fine, but I can't seem to get the link text using my code. It always returns undefined. Here's my code:

`$("a[href^='http']").eq(i).innerHTML`

 (i is the variable in a for loop, just pretend it's some number)

`$("a[href^='http']").eq(i)` should return the element, right? So what am I missing?

Here's a snippet to show you what I mean:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body><a href="https://www.google.com/">link1</a><a href="https://www.google.com/">link2</a><a href="https://www.google.com/">link3</a>
</body>
<p id="log">Pretend this is the console: </p>
<script>
  for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += ($("a[href^='http']").eq(i).attr("href") + " (" + $("a[href^='http']").eq(i).innerHTML + ") / ");
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: use jquery way `$('a').attr('href')` give this a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

innerHTML is a method, not a property, use it like so: `$("a[href^='http']").eq(i).innerHTML()`

To clarify, the `.eq(i)` method returns not a `DOMElement`, but a `jQuery` object. jQuery objects have the `innerHTML()` method - which returns a string of the html inside the element referred to by the jQuery object.

On a side note - seeing as you are looking to get the text, not html, maybe you actually would be better off using the `.text()` method instead?

Comment: Yes, thanks for  the clarification. This is very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming below link is retuned by selector

```
<a href="http://chat.stackoverflow.com" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:6 })">chat</a>
```

if you want to retrieve Link text then try

```
$("a[href^='http']").eq(i).text()
```

if you want to retrieve Link URL then try

```
$("a[href^='http']").eq(i).attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all **a tag** and iterate it, you can get the **href values** as code below:

```
$("body").find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Check this out, **https://jsfiddle.net/mogaax3g/**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the code above to work as follows.  As has been mentioned in comments what JQuery returns is a JQuery object. To access the actual element use an index after the JQuery object.

```
$("a[href^='http']")[i].innerHTML
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body><a href="https://www.google.com/">link1</a><a href="https://www.google.com/">link2</a><a href="https://www.google.com/">link3</a>
</body>
<p id="log">Pretend this is the console: </p>
<script>
  for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += ($("a[href^='http']").eq(i).attr("href") + " (" + $("a[href^='http']")[i].innerHTML + ") / ");
  }
</script>

</html>
```